# mypy: How to "convert" variable length tuple back to fixed length tuple?

Tags: python, mypy

Python code:

```
t = (1,2,3)
t = tuple(x+1 for x in t)
```

[mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html) complains:

```
2: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[int, ...]", variable has type "Tuple[int, int, int]")
```

What should I do to avoid that error? This does not help:

```
t = (1,2,3)
t = tuple(x+1 for x in t)[0:3]
```

This "works":

```
from typing import Tuple
t: Tuple[int, ...] = (1,2,3)
t = tuple(x+1 for x in t)
```

But I actually don't want `t` to be a variable-length tuple.

I can of course tell mypy to ignore the line:

```
t = (1,2,3)
t = tuple(x+1 for x in t) # type: ignore
```

Or repeat myself:

```
t = (1,2,3)
t = (t[0]+1, t[1]+1, t[2]+1)
```

Or use a temporary variable to at least avoid repeating the `+1` part (which is more complex in the real world problem):

```
t = (1,2,3)
tmp = tuple(x+1 for x in t)
t = (tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2])
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [cast](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/casts.html) to get around this.

```
from typing import cast, Tuple

t = (1,2,3)

t = cast(Tuple[int, int, int], tuple(x+1 for x in t))
```